# DialogFragment PositiveButton NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I got a crash from one of users (Samsung, Android 5) on PositiveButton.setBackgroundColor. It occured only one time and I can't repeat it.
This is the code:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...
        activity = getActivity();
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        alertDialogBuilder.setCustomTitle(layout);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(returnDialogView());
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.btn_save, null);
        mAlertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        mAlertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface d) {

                mPositiveButton = mAlertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                mPositiveButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.brand_gray));
                mPositiveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if(customerEditMode){
                            showFieldsOverCustomer();
                        }else {
                            save();
                        }
                    }
                });
private final TextWatcher  mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
...
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            if (mInputCardNumber.getText().toString().equals("")){
                mPositiveButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.brand_gray)); //Here is the NullPointer Exception
private View returnDialogView() {
...
mInputCardNumber.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);
}
```

The code works fine and nobody had the problem with it. Here is the Exception:

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException    
my.package.ui.fragment.dialog.NewTransactionDialogFragment$2.afterTextChanged (NewTransactionDialogFragment.java:275)
    android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged (TextView.java:8699)
    android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:4701)
    android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:4545)
    android.widget.EditText.setText (EditText.java:101)
    android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:4520)
    ...
```

The button is never GONE until the dialog is dismissed. I have no idea why it occured. And how can I fix it.

Comment: where is mInputCardNumber created?

Comment: you should change  `getResources().getColor(R.color.brand_gray)` to `getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.brand_gray)`

Comment: @Ankii Rawat. What is the difference?

Comment: @Ankii Rawat, it is **exactly** the same thing, there is no difference between the 2, getResources() in Fragment only does activity.getResources(), you can see that in [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.java#Fragment.getResources%28%29)

Comment: You can put a breakpoint at moment when you set a value of mPositiveButton and be sure it was set at all. Can you check this?

Comment: @Orest Savchak, it is. And it works in all cases, only one crash occured and i can't discover why and repeat it.